# Importing everything to the current namespace from a module in ipython

Tags: namespaces, ipython

I want to import everything in a module to the global namespace in an IPython session. So I tried `from <module> import *`, but that doesn't work. Although this works as expected in a python session. How can I do this in IPython?

I realise this is bad practice, but I just want to do this for an interactive session for a frequently used module.

Comment: It should work. What module are you trying it with, and what version of IPython?

Comment: @ThomasK I use a data analysis framework called [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/). I'm trying with the python bindings for this framework (called PyROOT). I have asked my colleagues, and all of them seem to see the same behaviour. After your comment, I tried to do the same with the os module and it worked. So I guess the problem is with PyROOT.

Comment: Any ideas what could be the problem with PyROOT? It would be good if I could include this information in my bug report to the devs.

Comment: It could still be a bug with IPython - imports should work exactly the same way as in a plain Python shell. What version of IPython are you using? I've not come across any problems with imports, but if you want to try the [ipython-user](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-user) mailing list, someone might know more.

Comment: I'm using IPython 0.12. I'll try posting on the ipython-user list. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from ROOT import *` is not supported by PyROOT under IPython.  Here is the warning from ROOT 5.34/09:

```
UserWarning: "from ROOT import *" is not supported under IPython
```